# pgfplots - How can I fill the background to a "node near a coordinate"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to have the nodes/values for each plot fill with `white`, so the grids get overdrawn, so to speak. Is this possible?

(Note: I only activated the major grid for `x` for the sake of the thread.)

### Picture with numbers/nodes on grid

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
amsmath,
tikz,
pgfplots,
pgfplotstable
}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{force-stats.txt}
Stats,Min,MinStdDev,MinCIP95,Max,MaxStdDev,MaxCIP95
Fx,-70.35,0.5,0.6,60,1,0.5
Fy,-40,0.5,0.6,50,1.91,1.5
Fz,-20,0.42,0.6,40,4,0.5
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{force-stats.txt}{\tableabcdef}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
scale only axis=true,
width=5cm,
height=7cm,
%
xlabel={Force components},
ylabel={Force in N},
%
ybar,
%
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
%
enlarge x limits={0.3},
enlarge y limits={0.2},
%
symbolic x coords={Fx,Fy,Fz},
%
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
xticklabels={{\(F_{x}\)},{\(F_{y}\)},{\(F_{z}\)}},
]
\addplot+[nodes near coords align={above}] plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table [col sep=comma, x=Stats, y=Max, y error=MinCIP95] {\tableabcdef};
\addplot+[nodes near coords align={below}] plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table [col sep=comma, x=Stats, y=Min, y error=MinCIP95] {\tableabcdef};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `every node near coord/.style={fill=white}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `pgfplots` manual:

> `/pgfplots/every node near coord  (style, no value)`
>   A style used for
>   every node generated by nodes near coords. It is initially empty.

So (`Ctrl-F NEW` to find the relevant line in the block of code):

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
  amsmath,
  tikz,
  pgfplots,
  pgfplotstable
}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{force-stats.txt}
  Stats,Min,MinStdDev,MinCIP95,Max,MaxStdDev,MaxCIP95
  Fx,-70.35,0.5,0.6,60,1,0.5
  Fy,-40,0.5,0.6,50,1.91,1.5
  Fz,-20,0.42,0.6,40,4,0.5
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{force-stats.txt}{\tableabcdef}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      scale only axis=true,
      width=5cm,
      height=7cm,
      %
      xlabel={Force components},
      ylabel={Force in N},
      %
      ybar,
      %
      xmajorgrids=true,
      ymajorgrids=true,
      %
      enlarge x limits={0.3},
      enlarge y limits={0.2},
      %
      symbolic x coords={Fx,Fy,Fz},
      %
      xtick=data,
      nodes near coords,
      every node near coord/.style={fill=white},%NEW
      xticklabels={{\(F_{x}\)},{\(F_{y}\)},{\(F_{z}\)}},
      ]
      \addplot+[nodes near coords align={above}] plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table [col sep=comma, x=Stats, y=Max, y error=MinCIP95] {\tableabcdef};
      \addplot+[nodes near coords align={below}] plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table [col sep=comma, x=Stats, y=Min, y error=MinCIP95] {\tableabcdef};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Adding the option to the surrounding `tikzpicture` has no effect (I guess the grid is drawn later in this case), but as you can see, adding it to the `axis` works.

The result is not necessarily pretty, though:

[image]